# heroku, bash: rake: command not found ,Windows 10

Tags: ruby, bash, heroku, rubygems, rake

I have searched through the slack forums and nothing seems to be working for my instance!

A little background; I am working with a Angular1, Heroku-Postgresql, Nodejs, Ruby&Rails application. Previously developed by someone else and has been passed down to me.

When I run in Windows Powershell

```
heroku rake db:migrate -a [app]
```

my console returns

```
Running rake db:migrate on [app]... up, run.7474 (Free) bash: rake: command not found
```

I have tried "*heroku run rake db:migrate*", does not work.

Installed *bash on ubuntu on windows*, added appropriate gem files, heroku, etc. created a symbolic link `sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake`
& still get `bash: rake: command not found`

Tried to *run rake* inside the heroku bash shell, and still get 'not found'.

Updated gemfiles, ruby files, added ruby bin to my environment variables.

So what gives? I am not familiar with Bash Ubuntu. Any guidance on what steps to take/try would be tremendous help.

Comment: have you installed `rake` on your bash on windows setup ? is it on the $PATH ? is `heroku` a windows command or a linux command ?

Comment: heroku is a windows command. All of my files are windows files.
In the bash ubuntu shell i can not change directories to my app files, i keep getting "bash: /mnt/c/: Is a directory"

Answer (score -1):

You're running that command on heroku platform.

And, as seen on [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake), you should run your command as

> heroku run rake db:migrate -a [appname]

My guess would be that you have something in some script that tries to execute rake.

You can use the --trace argument to see the detailed execution.

Comment: I've used run rake & rake both have returned the same result

Comment: If you don't give any more info it's harder to help